# F# list transposition with list list list?

Tags: f#

In F#, how would I make the list transposition function compatible with an int list list list ?

```
let rec transpose = 
   function
    | (_::_)::_ as M -> List.map List.head M :: transpose (List.map List.tail M)
    | _ -> []
```

It looks like this only works with `int list list`. However, I have further grouped the inner most list to make `int list list list` .

Comment: Have you tried calling the function with an int list list list? What's the error message? I think it works fine.

Comment: How do you even define transposition for multi-dimensional structures?

Answer (score 2):

With an int list list list, it depends on which matrices you want to transpose: the inner ones or the outer one or both. In the last case it will depend on the transpositions order.

```
let rec transpose = function
| (_::_)::_ as M -> List.map List.head M :: transpose (List.map List.tail M)
| _ -> []

// (a (b (c))) -> (a (c (b)))
let transpose0 m = m |> List.map transpose

// (a (b (c))) -> (b (a (c)))
let transpose1 m = m |> transpose

// (a (b (c))) -> (b (c (a)))
let transpose2 m = m |> transpose |> List.map transpose

// (a (b (c))) -> (c (a (b)))  
let transpose3 m = m |> List.map transpose |> transpose

// (a (b (c))) -> (c (b (a)))  
let transpose4 m = m |> transpose |> List.map transpose |> transpose
```